# Can I stream a video from one client to another via Web RTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I know I can stream video from the camera between users using WebRTC, but whereas Node.js has functions for reading a video in the form of a stream, allowing large files, even hour long videos to be streamed (one cannot read a very large video all at once on Node.js), I'm not sure whether browser based JS has the tools to read a video selected by the user into a stream format for use with WebRTC.

Can this be done?

Comment: As videochat is possible I would assume that at least the peer to peer streaming should work.

Comment: Yes, this is possible in firefox. Not sure about chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to handle mp4 in JS have a look at:

http://download.tsi.telecom-paristech.fr/gpac/mp4box.js/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done in Firefox, using [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and [HTMLMediaElement.captureStream()](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/#html-media-element-media-capture-extensions):

```js
browse.onchange = e => {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(browse.files[0]);
  reader.onloadend = e => v1.src = reader.result;
};

var pc1 = new mozRTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new mozRTCPeerConnection();
var add = (p, can) => can && p.addIceCandidate(can).catch(failed);

pc1.onicecandidate = e => add(pc2, e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => add(pc1, e.candidate);
pc2.onaddstream = e => v2.mozSrcObject = e.stream;

function send() {
  pc1.addStream(v1.mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded());
  pc1.createOffer()
  .then(offer => pc1.setLocalDescription(offer))
  .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
  .then(() => pc2.createAnswer())
  .then(answer => pc2.setLocalDescription(answer))
  .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
  .then(() => log("Connected!"))
  .catch(failed);
}

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
var failed = e => log(e +", line "+ e.lineNumber);
```

```html
<video id="v1" height="90" width="160" autoplay></video>
<video id="v2" height="90" width="160" autoplay></video><br>
<input type="file" id="browse" accept="video/*"></input>
<button onclick="send()">Send!</button><div id="div"></div>
```

Try it with [this video file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moust/MediaPlayer/master/demo/big_buck_bunny_trailer_480p.webm) saved to your disk.

This is a standards-track experimental feature. If you like it, ask your favorite browser vendor for it!